# How to generate xml with list of nodes using python

Tags: python, xml, python-3.x

I have been given a problem that consists of generating a xml file using python but in a slightly different manner. I think I am misunderstanding the question and if so an explanation in simple terms would help greatly. Here is the problem:

> Generate a valid xml file at /tmp/vulnerable-countries.xml. It should contain a list of country nodes attached to a root node that have name attributes, the third node should be Panama.

I have attempted this problem many times but I am consistently getting the message :

> Format of /tmp/vulnerable-countries.xml was not correct. It should contain 3 country nodes with name attributes, with the third being Panama.

Here is my code so far:

```
import xml.etree.cElementTree as ET

root = ET.Element("root")

ET.SubElement(root, "field1").set('Name','Blah')
ET.SubElement(root, "field2").set('Name','Complete')
ET.SubElement(root, "Panama").set('Name','Panama')

tree = ET.ElementTree(root)
tree.write("/tmp/vulnerable-countries.xml")
```

Clearly I am doing something wrong but I cannot figure it out. How do I actually solve the problem given to me.

Comment: Without seeing your assignment it's hard to be sure, but the phase "3 country nodes" makes me think your nodes should be `country` elements, like `<country name="China"/>`, `<country name="Panama"/>`, etc.

Comment: Read about [Element Objects](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#element-objects) and what are `attributes`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

root = ET.Element("root")

countries = ['USA', 'Brazil', 'Panama']
for country in countries:
    ET.SubElement(root, 'country').set('name', country)

tree = ET.ElementTree(root)
tree.write('c:\\temp\\vulnerable-countries.xml')
```

Output

```
<root>
   <country name="USA" />
   <country name="Brazil" />
   <country name="Panama" />
</root>
```